# Export Old SQL table data as UPDATE for New Table (for WHERE id 's is the same)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an a new table with the column below:

`id , name , tell , email`

By mistake all values of `tell` & `email` were set to null.

I have a old backup of this table , without ~200 record (a little old)

How can I update new table with the old backup with just the `tell` & `email` columns?

For example export old table data as update query and execute it on the new table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ::

```
Update newTable nT
inner join oldTable oT
ON (nT.id=oT.id)
set nT.tell = oT.tell, nT.email=oT.email
```